# Height of Binary Tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree

I'm trying to implement a recursive method to calculate the height of a binary tree. Here is the "height"-code:

```
def HeightOfTree(self):
    if self.root is None:
        return 0
    else:
        ans=self._HeightOfTree(self.root)
        return ans

def _HeightOfTree(self,currentNode):
    if currentNode.hasleftChild():
        lheight=1+self._HeightOfTree(currentNode.leftChild)
    if currentNode.hasrightChild():
        rheight=1+self._HeightOfTree(currentNode.rightChild)
    if lheight > rheight:
        return (lheight+1)
    else:
        return (rheight+1)
```

When I try to call the function, I get the following error msg:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lheight' referenced before assignment
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: What is your tree is a single node?  Neither `lheight` or `rheight` will have a value.

Comment: A side note: you need to have a base case whenever you use recursion.  Otherwise, the function will never end (or it will break down).

Answer (score 3):

If you're setting the value of a variable in an `if` block and you try to use it later, make sure that it's declared before the block so that if the `if` doesn't happen, it still exists.

Wrong:

```
if False:
    x = 3
print(x)
# UnboundLocalError
```

Right:

```
x = 0
if False:
    x = 3
print(x)
# 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `UnboundLocalError` because the values `rheight` and `lheight` are not created in the case that `leftChild` or `rightChild` are `None`.

It would be simpler if you defined a base case of `_HeightOfTree(None) == 0`:

```
def _HeightOfTree(self,currentNode):
    if currentNode is None:
        return 0
    return 1 + max(self._HeightOfTree(currentNode.leftChild), self._HeightOfTree(currentNode.rightChild))
```